# Getting NSData length zero? Error: Cocoa error 60

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nsdata

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,   NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:currentVideoDownload];

filePath = [filePath stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[responseData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

NSError *error;

NSData *mediaData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath options:NSDataReadingMapped   error:&error];

NSLog(@"Length:%d Error:%@",[mediaData length],[error localizedDescription]);
```

> LOG value: Length:0 Error: The operation could not be completed.
>   (Cocoa error 60)

Data is saving on file path properly but while fetching data from same path getting zero.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you know the data is being saved properly if you're not checking the return value of `-writeToFile:atomically:`? Also are you sure you want to use `-stringByAppendingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:` on a file path? Maybe `-stringByExpandingTildeInPath:` is more appropriate... You can also try logging `error.userInfo` to get more details about why the read operation failed.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann...thanks.. responseData is the data coming from server...in method connectionDidFinishLoading: . I am testing on simulator...the responseData write successfully to path i.e filePath. when I go to that path I can play the file manually. but when I am using the same filePath to get NSData it's get zero..

Comment: @MarkAdams....Thanks...I used error.userInfo...getting this:  Error:{
    NSFilePath = "/Users/Altu/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/5.0/Applications/75D3B5E2-C6BD-46B3-8F61-1FAC3D291070/Documents/test.mp4";
    NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 \"The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. No such file or directory\""

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are not writing to a writable file path. This is most likely because you are escaping the file path, which is not necessary, and in fact could cause IO reads/writes to fail if the escaped path does not exist. Percent escapes should only be used for HTTP requests, or related NSURL operations. Try removing the line:

```
filePath = [filePath stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```